# How is "He who Remains" different from "Kang the Conqueror"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021, ant-man-and-the-wasp-quantumania

My confusion starts from the ending of the TV show "Loki", where

> "He who remains" dies and time lines branch off.

Watching "Ant-man and the Wasp : Quantumania" we learned about his variants and specifically Kang the Conqueror.

Is "He who Remains" the same character Kang the conquerer?
They both seem on a mission to unite timelines into one sacred.

Comment: I suspect when "he who remains" died the infinity of Kang's re-emerged and fought amongst themselves a second time which we see in Ant-man.  However proving the difference between a second Kang war and a first depends on just how strongly a sacred timeline(s) are ones that don't have Kangs.  So this is just my opinion.  Timelines appear to naturally branch in the MCU.  I'd speculate that it is due to time traveling sub atomic particles causing nonstop branches forming like how Stark's time travel created a duplicate past that branched going forward.

Comment: @Mocas - You seem to be asking a few different questions here: 1) _"How is "He who Remains" different from "Kang the Conqueror"?"_ 2) _"how and why did they come into existence?"_ 3) _"Is the fight between these variants related to what he explained on the last episode of Loki?"_. We prefer questions to focus on a single question, so you should probably decide what your _main_ question is, and remove the others. You could also post one or more separate questions to ask about the other points.

Comment: @LogicDictates I understand, it is just that I don't understand the whole flow of kang variants from before before Loki till now.

Comment: @Mocas - I don't really get the question as it's currently phrased. You mention He Who Remains and "his variants," including Kang the Conqueror specifically, but then go on to ask if He Who Remains and Kang are the same person. It sounds like you're confused as to what a variant is. Is right? If so, I'd rephrase the question to specifically ask about the nature of variants (or maybe post a new question asking about that, since this question already has an answer).

Comment: @LogicDictates it just feels wrong to open a new question for every follow up question to an answer I get, that's why I wanted an explanation to what happened to all Kang variants from start to now

Comment: @Mocas - If you have several questions, they should be asked separately; it makes life easier for people attempting to answer your question/s, since they only have to deal with one question per answer, rather than several. That said, I've been trying to figure out if there may be a single underlying question here that you haven't directly asked, but that would resolve some or all of your other questions. That's why I asked if you're confused about what a variant is; if you are confused about that, then explaining that could resolve your other questions. You didn't answer that question, though.

Comment: @LogicDictates I know what a variants is, I just don't understand the flow of these variants through time and timelines, who appears where because of what.

Comment: @Mocas - I feel like there has to be some confusion about what a variant is, either on your part or mine. Because one of the questions you asked was whether He Who Remains and Kang the Conqueror are the same person, which doesn't make much sense as a question if your understanding of the term 'variant' is the same as mine.

Comment: @LogicDictates I tried to delete the question but I can't now.

Comment: I feel the title and the body don't match, the title asks how is he different? and the body asks is he even different?

Answer (score 13):

[He Who Remains](https://www.marvel.com/characters/he-who-remains) is a variant of [Kang](https://www.marvel.com/characters/kang), just as Sylvie is a variant of Loki and Throg is a variant of Thor. In an interview with [GamesRadar+](https://www.gamesradar.com/jonathan-majors-interview-the-harder-they-fall-netflix-ant-man-3/), the actor said that HWR and Kang are different characters:

> The character is different so you move a different way; my psychology
> has shifted because of the character. He’s just a different guy. He
> Who Remains is not in Ant-Man. It’s Kang.

As for the ominous line "See you soon", [Den of Geek](https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/kang-the-conqueror-he-who-remains-different-in-the-mcu/) and [Inverse](https://www.inverse.com/entertainment/loki-episode-6-kang-vs-thanos-finale) agree that he's referring to his variants.

Comment: If Kang the Conquerer is not "He who remains" , then why when Sylvie killed the latter he said "see you soon"?

Comment: @Mocas he is not being literal. He who remains created a multiverse where other Kang variants didn't exist.  When that failed he knew the dangerous variants of himself would be back.  So it is him in variant form - not him as that specific version who just died - that will be seeing them soon.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: he could also be literal. Since HWR can time-travel, a younger self may have met Loki and Sylvie in their future. We clearly can't know right now

Comment: @Taladris I agree, he *could* be being literal. He Who Remains was basically stuck in a time loop. Sylvie broke the loop. "See you soon" could be referring to a *past* version of HWR. Past for him, future for Sylvie/Loki.